# Setting Z-Index in DataBound items on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, data-binding, canvas, z-index

I am trying to bind a list of items to an `ItemsControl`, using a `Canvas` layout, where the item has multiple "levels".  This is easiest to explain using an image:

[image: Problem]

My lower level is a drop-shadow in this case.  Because I assumed the drop shadow would be attached to the main element (a `Button`), I created another visual element, a Border, which sits behind the Button and has the shadow attached.  What I would like is for all of my shadow elements to be at the same overall `ZIndex`, and all of the Button elements to be above them.

In practice, it appears that WPF renders the contents of my template as a single UI element, essentially flattening the `ZIndex`es within it.  Is there any way I can make it so that the `ZIndex` values are not flattened?

I have created a sample below which shows the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="600" Background="White">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DropShadowEffect Color="Blue" BlurRadius="75" x:Key="ActionDropShadow" />

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="myData" XPath="Data/Items">
      <x:XData>
        <Data xmlns="">
          <Items>
            <Item X="50" Title="AAA" />
            <Item X="100" Title="BBB" />
            <Item X="150" Title="CCC" />
          </Items>
        </Data>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BoxTemplate">
      <Grid>
        <Border Background="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Effect="{StaticResource ActionDropShadow}" />
        <Button Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Title}" />
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="list" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BoxTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myData},XPath=*}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
          <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPath=@X}" />
          <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="50" />
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        </Style>
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
      <Border Panel.ZIndex="5" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" Width="50" Height="80" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Effect="{StaticResource ActionDropShadow}"  />
      <Button Panel.ZIndex="10" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" Width="50" Height="80" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="AAA" />
      </Button>
      <Border Panel.ZIndex="5" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="100" Width="50" Height="80" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Effect="{StaticResource ActionDropShadow}" />
      <Button Panel.ZIndex="10" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="100" Width="50" Height="80" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="BBB" />
      </Button>
      <Border Panel.ZIndex="5" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="150" Width="50" Height="80" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Effect="{StaticResource ActionDropShadow}" />
      <Button Panel.ZIndex="10" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="150" Width="50" Height="80" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="CCC" />
      </Button>
    </Canvas>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Databinding Version</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">What it should look like</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the bound objects are wrapped in a `ContentPresenter` all internal `ZIndex` settings will be ignored, so you cannot do what you described. You might be better off creating an `ItemsControl` for each layer.

Comment: That was the conclusion I'd come to so far too.  I'm hoping there's a method that doesn't involve a second ItemsControl

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent `ContentPresenter` and set `ZIndex` on that.

E.g:

```
var parent = (UIElement) VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((UIElement) sender);
parent.SetZIndex(parent, z);
```